# sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected error

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I'm executing a script which looks like this.

```
diff <(grep eth0 /proc/net/dev) <(sleep 1; grep eth0 /proc/net/dev)
```

and I always got the `sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`
I tried writing it as a .sh file, and tried the different shebang lines.
I need to create a script that will execute this.

Comment: Where does Python come in?

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/bash`

`import os,sys`

`p = os.popen('awk').readlines()`

`print p`

Comment: that's my short script, I was trying to get the upload and download rate of my interface.

Comment: @VanDamme: Consider updating your original post than writing a comment with a [MCVE]

Comment: sorry @HelloWorld, I'm a new guy here. Thanks

Comment: Advice for new guys: read the comments you are being given and follow their advice.

Comment: Sorry ed morton, I was in a hurry yesterday. thanks for the advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<(command)` is a bashism called [Process substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html)

You have to run your script with bash, eg do `bash script.bash`

Or if you want to use sh, you could write the results to a file, like this :

```
grep eth0 /proc/net/dev > file1 
sleep 1 ; grep eth0 /proc/net/dev > file2 
diff file1 file2
```

Comment: Sir, I tried to write with bash but I still get the same output

Comment: What are you running exactly ? Have you tried the second solution I have ?

Comment: I just write the awk command at a .sh file and run it, am I wrong ? I'm new to bash scripting. I just need to print the output.

Comment: You just need to run `bash script.bash`. If that doesn't work, can you post the output of `bash --version ` ?

Comment: it works! I just like to ask, I've got the output
`123.123 kb/s 123.123 kb/s`

Next question if you don't mind.
I like to catch that values, how am I suppose to do that ?

Comment: Please open a new question for that, but only if you can't find anything by yourself in the next hour

Comment: Thanks sir edi9999. I'll try to find it as soon as I can

Answer (score 0):

I thing you are running this script `sh code.sh`. This means you are using `sh` to run the script, but this code implies it's been written for `bash`.

On some systems `sh` and `bash` are the same, but on others they are not; and, when invoked as `sh`, `Bash` turns off some non-POSIX features. So it's important to use the right shell and the right invocation.

Use `bash code.sh` or better still, make the script executable (`chmod a+x code.sh`) and then run it directly (`./code.sh`)